# "The MobileFirst server is unreachable. Response Code: " error with Maximo Work Execution 7.6.3.1 IFIX 001

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

Maximo Work Execution 7.6.3.0 was functioning on android device (7.1.2).  Updated to Work Execution 7.6.3.1 Ifix 001 which also requires installation of IF201903191506 to mobilefirst.  Now when attempting to login we are receiving message "The MobileFirst server is unreachable.  Response Code: ".   Does not seem as if the request is reaching mobilefirst as we are not seeing anything in the mf logs.  We are seeing below through adb logcat:

```
10-22 10:52:03.760 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.719[ERROR]                 
[ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: 
file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.761 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.722[ERROR] 
[ERROR]=== handled: false", source: 
file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.761 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.725[ERROR] 
[ERROR][object Object]", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.761 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(44)] "console.trace", source: 
file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/exception/PlatformRuntimeException.js (44)
10-22 10:52:03.761 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.730[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.762 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.732[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.762 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.734[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.763 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.736[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: true", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.763 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.738[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.763 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.740[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.763 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.742[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.764 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.744[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.764 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.749[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.776 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.751[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: true", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.785 16739 16808 I System.out: BackgroundLocationUpdatePlugin :: stop :: isEnabled Flag :: false
10-22 10:52:03.789 16739 16808 E BackgroundLocationServicesPlugin: ERROR UNBINDING SERVICEjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.flybuy.cordova.location.BackgroundLocationServicesPlugin$2@873c78f
10-22 10:52:03.789 16739 16808 W CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: BackgroundLocationServices450267838
10-22 10:52:03.789 16739 16808 W CordovaPlugin: Result was: "Failed To Stop The Service"
10-22 10:52:03.789 16739 16808 W CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: BackgroundLocationServices450267838
10-22 10:52:03.789 16739 16808 W CordovaPlugin: Result was: "Invalid action"
10-22 10:52:03.792 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.771[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.792 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.773[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.792 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.775[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.792 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.777[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.799 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.798[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.800 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.799[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: true", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.801 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.800[ERROR] [ERROR]=== Global promise rejection handling ===", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.802 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(328)] "2019-10-22, 10:52:03.801[ERROR] [ERROR]=== handled: false", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/js/platform/logging/Logger.js (328)
10-22 10:52:03.932  1205  2279 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@a79dd0c attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@a84f655, token = android.os.BinderProxy@dded766
10-22 10:52:04.112   478   478 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-22 10:52:04.666   780   780 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ215 from CPU3 to CPU0
10-22 10:52:04.806 16739 16739 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "The MobileFirst server is unreachable.  Response Code: ", source: file:///data/user/0/com.ibm.iot.maximoanywhere.workexecution/no_backup/www/default/dojo/dojo.js (2)
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

trying to remove feature from res/xml/config.xml, rebuild, and redeploy.  Any other ideas appreciated.